# Make only near faces of a cube invisible in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-room, cube, isometric

I'm trying to make an isometric style room where only the further back 3 sides of a cube are visible, based on the location of the camera but also maintain the shadows casted from these faces.

I have tried to do such using raycasts and updating the shadow casting mode of the GameObjects hit but haven't had any success.

Any ideas on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Just create a cube with its normals filpped and enable 2-sided shadow in the renderer.

Comment: What faces do you want to "maintain the shadows" of, the front or back?